# Dijkgraaf-Witten topological invariant

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, group-cohomology, characteristic-classes

We know that given a finite group $G$ and its group 4-cohomology class $w \in H^4[G;U(1)]$, we can obtain a DW topological invariant $Z_{G,w}(M^4)$ as the partition function of the DW theory on a closed 4-manifold $M^4$.

**Is it possible that a finite group $G$ may have two different 4-cohomology classes $w$ and $u$, such that they give rise to  the same DW topological invariant** (ie $Z_{G,w}(M^4) = Z_{G,u}(M^4)$  for any closed $M^4$).

When the group $G$ has an outer automorphism and if $w$ and $u$ are 
related by the outer automorphism, then $Z_{G,w}(M^4) = Z_{G,u}(M^4)$. Here I would like to ask if there are examples beyond outer automorphism.

In 3-dimensions, there are some dramatic examples beyond outer automorphism that $Z_{G,w}(M^3) = Z_{H,u}(M^3)$ even when $G\neq H$.

Comment: If $w$ and $u$ differ by a coboundary, then of course this will be true, because the Dijkgraaf-Witten invariants only depend on the cohomology class of the cocycle you twist by. Apart from that, I know of no examples where the theories coincide, and would expect such agreements to be a coincidence.